# Strategy of hittesting small target on Android

Tags: android, hittest

I am porting a desktop application that expects mouse-like precision input to Android, and is facing a design decision that I am not familiar with: hit test small target on screen.

The problem I have is there are often situations that multiple targets are clustered to a small region, with their distances smaller than what I can easily use my finger to accurately touch.  I can zoom in the image and I can then distinguish them, but the requirement want touch ability at no zoom.

I am considering the following two strategies:

1) Make the hit test region larger than the original object, by 50~100%, or

2) Check distance (< threshold) between the hit test regions and actual touch event location

Are there other commonly used practices that I should also take into consideration?

Comment: I would go with option 1. Are you familiar with the Chrome Browser for Android? Evertime you click something which is to small to identify it zooms very nicely.

Comment: @Ahmad you mean the magnifier they show when there are many links clustered in a small area? I like that idea too!

Comment: yes. Plus, the chrome browser is open source (AFAIK), so you can take a look at that.

Comment: I just took a quick look at /src/chrome/browser/android/chrome_web_contents_delegate_android.cc (this should be where chromium creates the detail rectangle) and maybe I should spend some time translate it to Android SDK compatible java code...